# c# to Node.js - Flushing named pipe write buffer does not end stream

Tags: c#, node.js, stream, named-pipes

I'm writing two Windows applications (one C# and one Electron) that communicates with each other using named pipes. The c# client should send the message and then flush to end that message. But the NamedPipeClientStream does not end streams on the Node side when flushing the buffer:

```
// C# client
public class Client
{
    private NamedPipeClientStream _client;
    private StreamWriter _writer;

    public Client(string pipeName)
    {
        InitClient();
    }

    private void InitClient()
    {
        _client = new NamedPipeClientStream("myPipe");
        _writer = new StreamWriter(_client);
        _client.Connect();
    }

    public void SendMessage(string response)
    {
        _writer.Write(response);
        _writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

This sends messages to a Node.js receiver:

```
// Node.js server
export class MessageHandler {
  private _pipePath;
  private _server: Server;
  private _stream: Socket;
  private _messageBuffer = "";

  constructor() {
    this._pipePath = "\\\\.\\pipe\\myPipe";
    this.initiateServer();
  }

  public initiateServer() {
    this._server = createServer({ allowHalfOpen: true }, (socket: Socket) => {
      this._stream = socket;

      this._stream.on("data", (buffer: Buffer) => {
        const message = buffer.toString();

        this._messageBuffer += message;
      });

      this._stream.on("end", () => {
        this.handleMessage();
      });
    });
  }

  private handleMessage() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I thought flushing the stream would trigger an end to the message?

What am I missing? Can I manually send an end to the stream from the C# client that I can detect in the Node side?

Thanks!

Comment: No.  Only closing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `Close` your `_writer` and `_client` after use, in order for them to release.

Your `SendMessage` should look like so:

```
_writer.Write(response);
_writer.Flush();
_writer.Close();
_client.Close();
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... So does that mean that I have to run InitClient() for every message?

Comment: @mottosson Sadly you will have to, at least as far as I know. The writer will ONLY release when it closes. Though I am not so very sure about the pipe... maybe it will automatically close, maybe it will stay open... Trail and error

Comment: @mottosson A piece of advice. Try to decouple the sending from the message-in. This will safe you a lot of work later and also prevent service spamming. Instead create a service that runs every one or two seconds that just pushes out all the messages that it collected (if any).

Comment: I ended up with a using statement for the NamedPipeClientStream and for StreamReader/StreamWriter for the two methods that handles the reading and writing of streams. As for the message buffer my application will never send more than one message at the time and listen to the response. But it's a good idea and I'll keep it in mind for next time when it might be more applicable. Thanks!